# Can anyone help me spot where my buffer overflow might be occuring?

Tags: float

I'm using dtostrf() to transcribe a float into a string for my touchscreen. I'd leave it as a float, but my screen orientation library function only works with a string.

So I have a char array, then a float value. then dtostrf().

```
char buffer[6]
float X; //changes each loop with incoming sensor data from pixy camera
float thingposition = X * .0064  //float calculations are performed.

void loop(){
Camera.Get_X();   //retrieves X from the camera. waits until X has been recieved via UART serial
dtostrf(buffer, 5, 2, thingposition) // writes float to string with a controled decimal place and all that - dtostrf(floatVar, minStringWidthIncDecimalPoint, numVarsAfterDecimal, charBuf);
Tft.drawString(buffer, 70, 215, 5, WHITE);   //print output to screen
}
```

Note that this is a simplified version. In my code I also have methods for overwriting my last string value on the LCD when the new one has changed.
I also have several "if" conditionals that control whether I write the buffer value to the screen or instead send an error message. Those things do not seem to be causing me problems though, except to say that my buffer overflows only occur when I cause the sensors to flip the conditionals at just the right interval.

For example, when I place my hand in front of the camera, that triggers the error message. Take my hand away, and then the number "thingposition" is printed to the screen. But if I time my hand just right, the buffer overflows and numbers loop across the screen. Usually this freezes the whole sketch. The best I can figure is that since dtostrf() does not check bounds, and since the calculated float values can be longer than the buffer has room for, that sometimes dtostrf() tries to write too many digits to the buffer. Something timing-related seems to trigger the problem, but what I need is some way to prevent the overflow in the first place.

I've tried rounding "thingposition" to a certain number of sigfigs, but I can't seem to truncate it at the desired decimal point. That shouldn't matter though, since dtostrf has controls for the minimum total length including the decimal point, as well the number of digits after the decimal. I also tried making sure that the last byte in my char array is null by adding this right after dtostrf():

```
stringval[5] = NULL;   //make sure buffer is null-terminated to prevent buffer overflow
```

I've tried doubles, different ways of rounding, and anything I could find, but the problem has persisted for several weeks and a few steady days worth of searching for a solution. I'll be glad to provide further information if anyone has any ideas on what to try. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If `thingposition` is `100000` or more, then `dtostrf()` _will_ use more than 5 characters to represent the number. It will use no more than 2 decimal digits (less if they won't fit in 5 characters), but it _won't_ compromise the main number to fit it inside your buffer. If you don't want that, clip the number to less than `100000`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using "simplified code" is that your 'simplification' may not have captured your problem. But I will take your code as given and assume that it's correct (which I'm afraid it isn't).

```
var
    char buffer[6]  // Won't compile - no semicolon (';')
    float X;        // Uninitialised value - could be 1000000000000
    float thingposition = X * .0064 // No ';', and .0064 of 10000000000 is huge!

void loop(){
    Camera.Get_X(); // Should this be "X = Camera.Get_X();" ?
    dtostrf(buffer, 5, 2, thingposition)  // No ';'. You NEED to recalculate thingposition!
```

If the above code is a good representation of what you've got, you seem to be assuming that you define the formula once (in the `thingposition` line), and it automatically applies that formula, like Excel, when you change its input, `X`. Sorry, programs don't work that way.

Once you calculate `thingposition`, it becomes independent of where it came from. If you change other variables, `thingposition` kees its value until you explicitly change it.

How do you fix it? You recalculate `thingposition` every time:

```
var
    char buffer[6];      // Hopefully big enough - see below
    float X;             // Used by Camera.Get_X()
    float thingposition;

void loop(){
    X = Camera.Get_X();        // Get X from Camera
    thingposition = X * .0064; // Calculate thingposition
    dtostrf(buffer, 5, 2, thingposition);
```

Note that `dtostrf()` will try to obey your size parameters, **BUT**. If the float is larger than your maximum size, it WILL print out the full number anyway. That is, if `thingposition` is `1000`, it will produce 5 characters all right: `"1000."`. But if it's `1000000`, it will produce `"1000000"` which is seven characters. You need to ensure that `buffer` is big enough to handle larger numbers than you expect.

Do the maths. If `X` is guaranteed to be between `0` and `255`, then multiplying it by `0.0064` will result in a maximum value of `1.632`, so the above `dtostrf()` woud produce `" 1.63"`. No problem!

Comment: I'm interested in your comments on dtostrf() and buffer size. Not much of the other stuff applies, because of course I calculate at every loop. Apologies for not including everything, but I didn't want to take up all your time and bore you. Also it's proprietary. I didn't think much of laying out the whole thing because I had assumed anyone would overlook all that and focus on the buffer, assuming all else is functional.

Comment: My floats are almost always guaranteed to be a little longer than the buffer after the calculation is performed. I'd like to cut them off at the appropriate digit after rounding if I could because I think that would solve the problem. dtostrf() seems to handle it well... until it doesn't.

Comment: And there's your problem. `dtostrf()` won't "lie" in its output. Rounding's OK, but truncating orders of magnitude? Like I said: either increase the buffer size going into `dtostrf()`, or be explicit and truncate the number first: do a `thingposition = fmod(thingposition, 100000);` to knock off the hundred-thousands-and-above digits that won't fit. Then the onus is on you rather than the function!

Comment: I'm a little confused. You said that dtostrf() would produce "1.63" from     1.632. But you also are saying that dtostrf() can't lie to adjust its output. Is that a contradiction? And I'm not sure what you mean by "truncating orders of magnitude". the float value 1.63 is the same magnitude as 1.632, it's just been reduced an order of precision. Also, the function fmod() does not seem to work for truncating ending digits, and I can't find a function that does. In fact, your example seems to add more digits.

    `Serial.println(fmod(x, 100000),24);`

    output: `9.123456954956054687500000`

Comment: That is, if x = 9.123456789

Comment: I said "`dtostrf()` won't lie in its output". By "lie" I meant outputting "21.01" if the number was 987654321.012345 - which some people expect when they ask for ",5,2". I went on to say that rounding's OK, since that's (one of) its jobs. I then went on to say that if you wanted to print out "21.01" for that large number, you needed to chop off the higher digits yourself, which is what `fmod()` does - `fmod(f, 100);` If you're having decimal rounding problems, you have yet to state what you're getting versus what you expect...